Found matching element but it disappeared while waiting
I'm working on the SAP Hybris e-commerce platform and encountered a Cypress issue while trying to click on a product in the product list. Cypress successfully finds the product by its code. The product list from Hybris organizes products by market, and I was trying to interact with a product in the Slovakia market.
I used the class name of the product, but since there are multiple elements with the same class name on the page, I used the .eq(8) command to target the 9th element. However, Cypress initially couldn't find the element. I've thought it was because it was outside the viewport. To resolve this, I added the .scrollIntoView() command to scroll the page down so that Cypress could find and interact with the element.
The final command I've used looks like this:
cy.get('span.yw-coll-browser-hyperlink').eq(8).scrollIntoView().should('be.visible').click();


As you can see on the screenshot the Cypress error says:

We initially found matching element(s), but while waiting for them to
become actionable, they disappeared from the page. Common situations
why this happens:

Your JS framework re-rendered asynchronously
Your app code reacted to an event firing and removed the element


Here is the HTML element I'm trying to interact with:
<span id="kAYZbx60" class="yw-coll-browser-hyperlink z-label" title=" [] - VEEV Sleeve Lake [G0000499] - Slovakia Product Catalog : Staged"> [] - VEEV Sleeve Lake [G0000499] - Slovakia Product Catalog : Staged</span>


In the meantime, I've tried using the following command, and it seems to be working fine:
cy.get('span.yw-coll-browser-hyperlink').contains("VEEV Sleeve Lake [G0000499] - Slovakia Product Catalog : Staged").scrollIntoView().should('be.visible').click({force:true});

I've used the .contains() command instead of .eq().

Cypress is not so good with sophisticated frameworks like SAP, it tends to get confused when the page refreshes. You may find Playwright gives better results.
